# Is there a bug in Chrome's CSS visibility rendering?

Tags: css, google-chrome

There seems to be odd behavior in Chrome 15+ when using this particular combination of CSS properties, namely an outer element with visibility hidden and fixed positioning and an absolutely or relatively positioned inner element that has an override on visibility.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:fixed;visibility:hidden;">
    <div style="position:absolute;visibility:visible;">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    document.write("<br />");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code snippet above produces this image when scrolled.
[image: Chrome visibility issue]

The fact that both relative and absolute positioning both reproduce the behavior can be chalked up to the fact that for this particular DOM absolute positioning is equivalent to relative positioning.

In the case that this markup is valid and does have defined behavior, this points to a bug in the browser/rendering engine, and it looks like a performance optimization gone bad, especially given that this behavior was introduced with the Chrome 15 update.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bHzWN/show/) courtesy of Sparky672

Update:

This behavior has been reported to the [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76126) and seems that the changeset that introduced the bug has been identified.

Comment: Bug exists in 16.0.912.63 m, too

Comment: It doesn't happen in jsfiddle, but create a basic web page, launch it and you can see it

Comment: And when you say 'Inspect element', Chrome sais like 'You ain't seen it, right?'

Comment: If it happens on a "basic web page", then it should happen here too:  http://jsfiddle.net/bHzWN/show/

Comment: I can see it happening in that link...

Comment: I never said it wasn't happening... I'm just responding to the OP who said it doesn't happen within a jsFiddle.

Comment: though I keep wondering - what on earth would you want to achieve with the code you posted?

Comment: Why don't you use display:none and display:block instead of buggy visibility?

Comment: display:none and visibility:hidden achieve completely different goals. This pattern is used in old code that is injected into thousands of web-pages and cannot be changed without much verification effort.

Comment: The bug exists for me using Chrome 16 (16.0.912.75) on Mac OS X "Lion" (10.7.2), but oddly doesn't happen with Safari 5.1.2 (7534.52.7), which also uses WebKit.

Comment: @rjb That could be attributed to Chrome 15 and Safari 5.1 using WebKit 535.* and 534.* respectively. Could be a regression introduced in WebKit.

Answer (score 36):

Yep, there is a bug, definitely: I managed to reproduce it in my version of Chrome too.

In case you'll want to fix it, you could add the “webkit's hasLayout” fix, `-webkit-transform:  translateZ(0);` to wrapper or inner element, this makes Chrome to render the block properly.

Here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/bHzWN/6/show/

Comment: Spoke to Paul Irish at Google who agrees with you and that this is a bug that needs to be reported here: http://goo.gl/AnJW5

Comment: Great fix! This seems to be the safest way of getting around the bug without changing too much.

Comment: Worked for me - thank you very, very much. "hasLayout"-like bugs in WebKit  24.0.1312.56 m, in 2013? *sigh*

Comment: I had a bug that didn't have to do with visibility, but rather toggling between display: block and display: none (jQuery hide/show). The -webkit-transform hack worked for me. The number of Chrome rendering bugs I come across is rather unfortunate.

Comment: 3 years later, I'm still experiencing the bug and translateZ(0) solved my problem.

Comment: @Andrew, February 2016 here, just ran into this issue, so it's still not fixed. I fixed it using Kizu's solution/hack as well.

Comment: I stumbled upon this discussion looking for a solution to a bug in Chrome not showing tooltips. I tried the translateZ(0) fix but didn't work for me. I finally managed to solve the problem by putting the tooltiptext inside a parent dummy <a class="tooltip"> element. Just leaving this comment in case anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bug. It seems to be a Web-kit regression bug that started happening in version 535, and is noticeable in many versions of Chrome even up through 18.x

kizu's hack is fine as a workaround until they address it again.