# Solution for fixed & hidden div bug on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Problem: A div with `visibility:visible` inside a parent div with `position:fixed` and `visibility:hidden` causes rendering problems in Google Chrome. [Images and examples can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568673/is-there-a-bug-in-chromes-css-visibility-rendering).

A week ago you could just add the `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)` to the parent div and bug solved. But it isn't working anymore:

- [Without `-webkit-transform`](http://jsfiddle.net/56rkcpyo/show/)
- [With the hack](http://jsfiddle.net/6czmxeLt/show/).

Both are bugged.

So, is there any solution? When you resize the window, it repaints the divs, also when you open the developer tools the bug disappears.

So I've been trying to force a repaint with javascript (jQuery):

```
jQuery(window).scroll( function() {
    jQuery("#parentDiv").addClass("nothing");
    jQuery("#parentDiv").removeClass("nothing");
});
```

And it **sometimes** works (when a textfield is displayed inside the inner div). Really weird. Also tried hiding and displaying the div, adding css properties (fixed, bottom:0...)
But nothing works fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT2: Seems like it only happens to me: 2 friends, using windows and the latest version (17.0.963.79) don't see the bug in the second link. But I still see it. I've reinstalled chrome under windows, and the bug is still there.
I also have cleared the cache, but nothing changes. Am I the only one????

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in the second fiddle you posted...

Comment: I have Linux Mint 12 KDE, and Google Chrome 17.0.963.79
I don't remember my windows chrome version, but I think it is the latest.
which version do you have??

Comment: changed my laptop, now it's not happening xD

Answer (score 3):

from my own experience when working with `scroll()`, all form-elements behave strangely, or do not function anymore.

You solution `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)` will fix it for webkit browsers, but all others browsers will trow a translated layer above all form-elements, result is that form-element are not accessible anymore.

scroll() is a great solution for just plain info (text- images), not for forms.